# Append bytes to string?

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, binary

I have a file I've opened in Python which I'm writing to another output file. I need it to be a multiple of 16 in filesize, so this is what I've devised:

```
 with open(input_file, 'rb') as infile:
     with open(output_file, 'wb') as outfile:
         while True:
             input_chunk = infile.read(64)

             if len(input_chunk) == 0:
                 break
             elif len(input_chunk) % 16 > 0:
                 input_chunk.extend([0 for i in range(len(input_chunk) % 16)])

             output_file.write(input_chunk)
```

Unfortunately, it fails to append the zeroes with:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'extend'
```

First, why do I have a string here, rather than an array of bytes? I'm reading the binary file in binary mode.

Second, if I'm dealing with a string, how do I write a number of bytes with the value `0` to the end of that string?

Comment: strings are immutable objects.

Comment: Maybe input_chunk = input_chunk + '\0' * (len(input_chunk) % 16)

Comment: Is there a way that I can read a file as arrays of bytes?

Comment: I think the issue is on the extend call.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First, why do I have a string here, rather than an array of bytes?

Because that's what `file.read` returns ...

> Second, if I'm dealing with a string, how do I write a number of bytes with the value 0 to the end of that string?

You can't write it onto that string because strings are immutable.  You can however write it onto a different string and create new strings by concatenation:

```
>>> import struct
>>> input_chunk = 'foo bar baz'
>>> input_chunk + struct.pack('16B',*([0]*16))
'foo bar baz\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>>
```

Note that if you know that you have 64 bytes and you want a string that is 80 bytes padded with nulls, `struct.pack` **will pad it automatically with nulls**:

```
struct.pack('80s',string_of_64_bytes)
```

> For the 's' format character, the count is interpreted as the size of the string, not a repeat count like for the other format characters; for example, '10s' means a single 10-byte string, while '10c' means 10 characters. If a count is not given, it defaults to 1. For packing, the string is truncated or padded with null bytes as appropriate to make it fit. For unpacking, the resulting string always has exactly the specified number of bytes. As a special case, '0s' means a single, empty string (while '0c' means 0 characters).

Comment: It sounds like OP is trying to do AES encryption. If that is the case, then the padding should not be all nulls.

It should be following [PKCS#7 Padding as per RFC 5652](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5652#section-6.3) and be padded with the the byte that is the value of each added byte.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 2.x, a `str` object is an "array of bytes".

If you need a mutable array, use a bytearray on versions 2.6+:

```
>>> a = bytearray('my_string')
>>> a.extend(' hello')
>>> str(a)
'my_string hello'
```

Otherwise:

```
>>> import array
>>> a = array.array('c', 'my_string')
```

Comment: You also have `bytearray` in 2.7.

Comment: Actually, `bytearray` is available since 2.6 [bytearray](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray)

Comment: @wasserfeder That makes `bytearray` a better choice then.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `bytearray` and you should be good as-is:

```
           input_chunk = bytearray(infile.read(64))
```

Though I would just use something like `[0] * (16 - len(input_chunk)%16)` instead of a list comprehension for the padding.

Answer (score 0):

You can pad your `input_chunk` like this

```
input_chunk += '\x00'*(-len(input_chunk)%16)
```

Comment: How can I convert an int into a byte like this? the `\x00` will need to be dynamic, as I'll be changing that to be the remainder of `len(input_chunk)%16`.